# Reference error not defined

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am getting reference error videodownload is undefined

```
<button id="download" onclick="videodownload()">download</button>
```

Syntax error unexpected identifier

```
function videodownload(){
            var fileName = <?php  echo $video_arr['video_link']; ?> // you need to get your filename, e.g. "video.mp4"
            window.location.href = 'https://ip address/testNxServer/trynewnew/menu/stream\video/download.php?filename=' + fileName;
            }
```

Output of above code using chrome developer console

```
var fileName = original/480p/01ccc8dbb9a2f812a50bfc0a7652c8b5aca6ab31480p.mp4 // you need to get your filename, e.g. "video.mp4"
```

I cant seem to find the problem.. Please help me.

Comment: This `<?php  echo $video_arr['video_link']; ?>` should be in quotes because it is a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the filename in quotes, since it's a string. `json_encode()` is the best way to convert a PHP value into the equivalent javascript literal; it will add the quotes, as well as any necessary escaping.

```
var fileName = <?php echo json_encode($video_arr['video_link']); ?>;
```